# How to pass argument in PrimeNG's SplitButton?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

This is my MenuItem array:

```
this.ButtonItems = [
  {label: 'Edit', icon: 'fa fa-pencil-alt', command: (x) => {
      this.onEditDocument(x);
  }},
  {label: 'Duplicate', icon: 'pi pi-times', command: (x) => {
      this.onDuplicate(x);
  }}
];
```

Both functions need a parameter of type string (item.id).

Here is my template:

```
<p-splitButton 
    label="Save" 
    icon="i-btn fa fa-search" 
    title="View document"
    (onClick)="onViewDocument(item.id)" 
    [model]="ButtonItems(item.id)"></p-splitButton>
```

The code doesn't compile. I was trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65383371/primeng-splitbutton-how-to-get-a-parameter-into-the-model) example but I don't understand it. How can I get this right?

**UPDATE:**

My splitbutton is next to each item in the following table:

```
<p-table 
    [value]="currentDocuments" 
    [responsive]="true" 
    [columns]="cols" 
    [paginator]="true" 
    [rows]="10" 
    [showCurrentPageReport]="true" 
    styleClass="p-datatable-responsive-demo" 
    currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {first} to {last} of {totalRecords} entries">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                <div class="header-no-overflow">{{col.header}}</div>
            </th>
            <th style="width: 60px;"></th>            
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-item let-columns="columns">
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns" >
                <span class="p-column-title">{{col.header}}</span>
                <div *ngIf="col.type != 'File Uploader'">
                    {{item[col.field]}}
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="col.type == 'File Uploader'">
                    <div *ngFor="let file of item[col.field]">
                        <a [href]="file.downloadUrl" target="_blank">{{file.name}} </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <ng-container *ngFor="let buttonItem of ButtonItems">
                    <p-splitButton 
                        label="Save" 
                        icon="i-btn fa fa-search" 
                        title="View document"
                        (onClick)="onViewDocument(item.id)" 
                        [model]="buttonItem(item.id)"
                    ></p-splitButton>
                </ng-container>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

I added this here to explain my scenario in more detail.

My MenuItem looks like so:

```
this.ButtonItems = [
      [{ label: 'Edit', icon: 'fa fa-pencil-alt', command: (x: string) => this.onEditDocument(x) }],
      [{ label: 'Duplicate', icon: 'pi pi-times', command: (x: string) => this.onDuplicateDocument(x) }]
    ];
```

I want to add split buttons on each of the items in the table. The two buttons (edit and duplicate should be moved to items in the splitbutton. Here is a image to illustrate what i mean: [image: image of table that should contain splitbuttons for eac item]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the linked example, the property `model` is bound to a function which is actually a bad idea. In a default change detection strategy setup, the function might get invoked for each change detection cycle.

In your case you might have to iterate over the `ButtonItems` array.

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let buttonItem of ButtonItems">
  <p-splitButton 
    label="Save" 
    icon="i-btn fa fa-search" 
    title="View document"
    (onClick)="onViewDocument(item.id)" 
    [model]="buttonItem"
  ></p-splitButton>
</ng-container>
```

#### Update

Each menu item needs to be an array instead of an object.

```js
this.ButtonItems = [
  [{ label: 'Edit', icon: 'fa fa-pencil-alt', command: (x) => this.onEditDocument(x) }],
  [{ label: 'Duplicate', icon: 'pi pi-times', command: (x) => this.onDuplicate(x) }]
];
```

Comment: I get the following error on [model]: Type 'MenuItem' is missing the following properties from type 'MenuItem[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more. Where do I pass the argument?

Comment: @ClintTheron: Again taking from the linked post, apparently each menu item must be an array instead of an object. I've updated the answer. Please see if it works.

Comment: Can you also declare this.ButtonItems. Thanks in advance

Comment: @ClintTheron: You mean something like `ButtonItems: any[] = []`?

Comment: Yes:) Your code doesn't pass item.id to [model]. Something like [model]="buttonItem(item.id)"

Comment: item.id is an id that I'm getting from an array I'm iterating over. Each item in this array have a splitbutton. I want to understand how to pass this id to the functions. I think I should do it in [model] property

Comment: @ClintTheron: In the linked post, `cmds(x)` function returns a common menu item for each call from the template with only the label changed (`label: "BAR for "+x`). In your case each menu item has different labels and different command callbacks. How would you handle them if the `buttonItem` is defined as a function like `buttonItem(x: any)` in the controller?

Comment: I updated my question to explain in more detail my markup. Kindly look at the updated code and answer accordingly

Comment: I added all that you should know to give full and complete answer. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3):

So with my specific scenario here is the solution:

template:

```
<td>
        <p-splitButton appendTo="body" label="Save" icon="pi pi-check" (onClick)="onViewDocument(item.id)" [model]="buttonActions[item.id]"></p-splitButton>
</td>
```

.ts:

```
buttonActions: {[id:string]: MenuItem[]} = {};  
  
this.currentDocuments.forEach(el => {
  this.buttonActions[el.id as string] = [
    {label: 'View', icon: 'pi pi-refresh', command: () => {
        this.onViewDocument(el.id as string);
    }},
    {label: 'Edit', icon: 'pi pi-times', command: () => {
        this.onEditDocument(el.id as string);
    }},

];
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I gave a try to others solution but they didn't work! so I have to find my own workaround for resolving this problem.
Here is the thing, the split-button has two events "onClick" & "onDropdownClick", the second event will be triggered before executing the command function of button options! so I'm setting my wished value on that event (I mean onDropDownClick) and then when I'm calling the command function I have that value. take a look at my code, and u definitely better understand what I'm talking about.

```
 <p-splitButton
                class="w-100"
                [label]="'SHARED.EDIT' | translate"
                [title]="'PRODUCTS.EDIT_PRODUCT' | translate"
                icon="pi pi-eye"
                (onClick)="editProduct(item.id)"
                [model]="recordMenuItems"
                (onDropdownClick)="handleActionsClick(item)"
              >
              </p-splitButton>

 public selectedProductForExecutingAction: any = null;

  public handleActionsClick(product) {
    this.selectedProductForExecutingAction = product;
  }

  public recordMenuItems: MenuItem[] = [
    {
      label: 'Copy',
      icon: 'pi pi-copy',
      command: (event) => {
        this.copy(this.selectedProductForExecutingAction.id);
      }
    },
    {
      label: 'Delete Product',
      icon: 'pi pi-times',
      command: (event) => {
        this.deleteProduct(this.selectedProductForExecutingAction);
      }
    }
  ];
```

Comment: At first,I think the solution like you and came here to check if any better solutions.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Esto es más claro para mí.

```
xxx.html
<p-splitButton icon="pi pi-print" label="Imprimir"
(onClick)="imprimirFactura(rowData)" [model]="cmds(rowData)"></p-splitButton>
```

```
//xxx.componente.ts
    cmds(row): any {
        const items = [
            {
                label: 'Acción 1', 
                icon: 'pi pi-clone', command: () => {
                    this.dummy(row);
                }
            },
            {
                label: 'Acción 2', 
                icon: 'pi pi-clone', command: () => {
                    this.confirmarPagoFactura(row);
                }
            },
        ];
        return items; (x); }}];   
    }
```